# Using Inspect Element to disable full-screen popup link?

Tags: html, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

I use a certain website to watch foreign videos, and recently they began shoving a bunch of annoying spam links that pop up on the site. One of these is an invisible link to a spam site that covers the entire page, making it so that you're forced to click on it if you want to do anything else on the page. You can see this yourself if you try going to the site, as you'll probably notice your cursor will look like it's hovering over a link no matter where on the page you put it: [miomio.us](https://miomio.us). It happens no matter what page on the site you go to, and even after you accidentally click on it, it tends to keep reappearing.

I am aware that the Inspect Element tool on Firefox/Chrome can be used to temporarily edit the HTML of the page, and I wanted to know how I might go about editing the code to get rid of this and preventing it from reappearing (I know that changes will all disappear when I refresh but I'm fine with only temporarily making it go away). This is the HTML of the element:

```
<div id="d9wrz21" style="position: fixed; inset: 0px; z-index: 2147483647; background: black none repeat scroll 0% 0%; opacity: 0.01; height: 750px; width: 1536px;"><a id="lkhin" href="http://au79nt5wic4x.com/hzdiwnivp?awvo=41&amp;refer=https%3A%2F%2Fmiomio.us%2F&amp;kw=%5B%22youtube%E3%83%90%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A8%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3%E5%8B%95%E7%94%BB%E5%80%89%E5%BA%AB%E3%81%8A%E7%AC%91%E3%81%84%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%82%A2%E3%82%A4%E3%83%89%E3%83%AB%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A7%E3%83%90%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A8%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3%E3%81%AE%E7%84%A1%E6%96%99%E5%8B%95%E7%94%BB%E3%82%92%E8%A6%96%E8%81%B4%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%80%82%22%5D&amp;key=09ebdae44542192f133e1224de135f65&amp;scrWidth=1536&amp;scrHeight=864&amp;tz=-5&amp;ship=&amp;pst=&amp;v=20.2.v.6&amp;res=7.1055&amp;dev=e" target="_blank" style="display: block; height: inherit;"></a></div>
```

If I try to right click on it in Inspect Element and click "Delete Node," the entire block of code simply automatically reappears. Trying to change the href also doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions on anything that can be done about this? I know nothing about HTML, so I would appreciate if responses could be put in layman's terms :D

Comment: You can probably hide it instead of deleting. Click it in devtools inspector and press `h` key or add `display: none !important` manually to element's style attribute.